# How to crawl html tag(I dont want text) with BeautifulSoup Bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

```
<div class="tioTrivia lightblue bottomRight show sticky" data-login-url="http://www.ntvspor.net/uyelik/giris?returnUrl=/haber/futbol/131009/uniteda-yeni-arjantinli?utm_source=ntvspor%26utm_medium=oyun%26utm_campaign=iste_oyun" data-article-url="/haber/futbol/131009/uniteda-yeni-arjantinli?utm_source=ntvspor&utm_medium=oyun&utm_campaign=iste_oyun&ref=isteoyun" data-profile-url="http://www.ntvspor.net/uyelik/profil" data-content-class="trivia-widget-position" data-start-place="bottom-right" data-show-points="true" data-article-id="Tivibu,Manşet,Futbol,Futbol,Spor Toto Süper Lig,Beşiktaş,Gençlerbirliği" style="transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out 0s, right 0.5s ease 0s; top: 832px;">
```

This HTML is my target. I want to crawl this line;

```
data-article-id="Tivibu,Manşet,Futbol,Futbol,Spor Toto Süper Lig,Beşiktaş,Gençlerbirliği"
```

Specially I need this line ;

```
"Tivibu,Manşet,Futbol,Futbol,Spor Toto Süper Lig,Beşiktaş,Gençlerbirliği"
```

I write this function but return None;

```
 def read_tags(self, news_url):
        try:

            self.checkRequests(news_url)
            tag = self.soup.find("div", {'class':'tioTrivia lightblue bottomRight show sticky'})
            if tag:
                tag = tag.get_text().encode(encoding='utf-8')
                return tag.lower()
            return
        except Exception, e:
            self.insertErrorLog('ntvspor.read_title', news_url, e)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code and sample HTML, `tag.get_text()` returns an empty string because there is no inner text within the `div` tag.

Why not just grab the value of the `data-article-id` attribute from the matched tag by referencing the attribute?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('''<div class="tioTrivia lightblue bottomRight show sticky" data-login-url="http://www.ntvspor.net/uyelik/giris?returnUrl=/haber/futbol/131009/uniteda-yeni-arjantinli?utm_source=ntvspor%26utm_medium=oyun%26utm_campaign=iste_oyun" data-article-url="/haber/futbol/131009/uniteda-yeni-arjantinli?utm_source=ntvspor&utm_medium=oyun&utm_campaign=iste_oyun&ref=isteoyun" data-profile-url="http://www.ntvspor.net/uyelik/profil" data-content-class="trivia-widget-position" data-start-place="bottom-right" data-show-points="true" data-article-id="Tivibu,Manşet,Futbol,Futbol,Spor Toto Süper Lig,Beşiktaş,Gençlerbirliği" style="transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out 0s, right 0.5s ease 0s; top: 832px;">''')
data = soup.find('div', class_='tioTrivia').get('data-article-id', '')
data = data.encode('utf8')

>>> data
'Tivibu,Man\xc5\x9fet,Futbol,Futbol,Spor Toto S\xc3\xbcper Lig,Be\xc5\x9fikta\xc5\x9f,Gen\xc3\xa7lerbirli\xc4\x9fi'
>>> print data
Tivibu,Manşet,Futbol,Futbol,Spor Toto Süper Lig,Beşiktaş,Gençlerbirliği
```

Also, you don't need to specify all values for the `class` attribute. In this case `tioTrivia` should be sufficient because the others (`lightblue bottomRight show sticky`) are presentational, not [semantic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML).

Answer (score 0):

As simple as:

```
for t in soup.select('.tioTrivia'):
    print t.get('data-article-id')
```